# In my iPad settings there is an app called null what is it?

Tags: applications

When I go to settings on my iPad it shows an app called null what is this? What do I do about it? Is it bad or nothing to worry about?

Comment: Where specifically in "settings" are you seeing this?  Can you also post a screenshot?

Comment: In my main settings

Comment: Answering "in my main settings" doesn't help us help you.  When I open settings [this](http://imgur.com/4e1baw0) is what I see, I'm having trouble visualizing where you are seeing "null".

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious where this app came from. According to the answer to this [question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7136864?start=0&tstart=0), it probably is an app that was incompletely synced with iTunes.

There's nothing to worry about, and you don't need to do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings-->General-->Storage&iCloud Usage-->Manage Storage. Then scroll down the apps to find null and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Null doesn't mean anything bad, it just means your iPad thinks there is an app but it can't get all the information required to display it, or the information doesn't exist.

If you don't see this "Null" app anywhere else, it may just be leftover from either a incomplete sync, an app may of not been completely deleted, or a variety of other reasons.

Usually a restart should fix it but if it doesn't it's nothing to worry about. If you know an app you recently uninstalled you may also want to try to reinstall and delete it again because it might be a leftover from a partially deleted app.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this app and all of a sudden the 'delay' between me pressing the keyboard and the letters/numbers appearing on the screen disappeared.  Made me wonder if it was some kind of spyware...